# Use GNU parallel to parallelise a bash for loop

Tags: python, unix, gnu-parallel

I have a for loop which runs a Python script ~100 times on 100 different input folders. The python script is most efficient on 2 cores, and I have 50 cores available. So I'd like to use GNU parallel to run the script on 25 folders at a time.

Here's my for loop (works fine, but is sequential of course), the python script takes a bunch of input variables including the `-p 2` which runs it on two cores:

```
for folder in $(find /home/rob/PartitionFinder/ -maxdepth 2 -type d); do
        python script.py --raxml --quick --no-ml-tree $folder --force -p 2
done
```

and here's my attempt to parallelise it, which does not work:

```
folders=$(find /home/rob/PartitionFinder/ -maxdepth 2 -type d)

echo $folders | parallel -P 25 python script.py --raxml --quick --no-ml-tree {} --force -p 2
```

The issue I'm hitting (perhaps it's just the first of many though) is that my `folders` variable is not a list, so it's really just passing a long string of 100 folders as the `{}` to the script.

All hints gratefully received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `echo $folders | parallel ...` with `echo "$folders" | parallel ...`.

Without the double quotes, the shell parses spaces in `$folders` and passes them as separate arguments to `echo`, which causes them to be printed on one line. `parallel` provides each line as argument to the job.

To avoid such quoting issues altogether, it is always a good idea to pipe `find` to `parallel` directly, and use the null character as the delimiter:

```
find ... -print0 | parallel -0 ...
```

This will work even when encountering file names that contain multiple spaces or a newline character.

Comment: gah! Two simple solutions. I wouldn't have figured the first out, but should have tried the second. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can pipe find directly to parallel:

```
 find /home/rob/PartitionFinder/ -maxdepth 2 -type d | parallel -P 25 python script.py --raxml --quick --no-ml-tree {} --force -p 2
```

If you want to keep the string in `$folder`, you can pipe the echo to xargs.

```
echo $folders | xargs -n 1 | parallel -P 25 python script.py --raxml --quick --no-ml-tree {} --force -p 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Makefile` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

FOLDERS=$(shell find /home/rob/PartitionFinder/ -maxdepth 2 -type d)

all: ${FOLDERS}

# To execute the find before the all
find_folders:
    @ echo $(FOLDERS) > /dev/null

${FOLDERS}: find_folders
    @ python script.py --raxml --quick --no-ml-tree $@ --force -p 2
```

and then run `make -j 25`

Be careful: use tabs to indent in your file

Also, files with spaces in the name won't work.